# Expanding Table Row Issue From Previous Solution

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the accepted solution to this problem found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897396/can-a-table-row-expand-and-close).

[Solution's JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfwYS/)

My goal is simply to have the table's row expand when clicked. This solution works great for me aside from one issue. Once a the expanded row is visible, if you click near the very bottom of the expanded row, the row will disappear and will not be able to be re-expanded. This is slightly different from the accepted solution. If you click the border under "name" after a row has been expanded, the solutions row will also disappear with no way to re-expand.

Here is the `JS` function:

```
$(function() {
    $("td[colspan=7]").find("p").hide();
    $("table").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $target = $(event.target);
        if ( $target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1 ) {
            $target.slideUp();
        } else {
            $target.closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
        }                    
    });
});
```

I will try to provide additional information if needed.

My `td` for only the expanding row has padding set to 0. If I give it some padding, clicking the padding, even before the row is expanded, will remove the whole expanding row.

**EDIT** To reproduce my issue click the border just under the 'N' of 'Name' in the previous solutions fiddle table after expanding a row.

**EDIT** Happens to my table if I click any part of the border.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change only one line in your jsfiddle and it will work:

Change `$target.slideUp();`to `$target.closest("td").children("p").slideUp();` , and you will be able to expand even if you click at border.

Answer (score 0):

I changed way to approach.

Please check the code and result by clicking the following link.

I hope that it is what you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/oLkxs1j4/3/

```
<style>
#table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

#table tr{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.expand-row{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.not-expand-row{
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.expand-data{
  display: none;
}
</style>
<table id = "table">
  <tr class = "expand-row">
    <td>Click to expand-1</td>
    <td>Click to expand-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class = "expand-data">
    <td colspan = "2">
      <br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <button class = "click-to-close">CLOSE</button>
    </td>
  </tr>  
  <tr class = "expand-row">
    <td>Click to expand-1</td>
    <td>Click to expand-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class = "expand-data">
    <td colspan = "2">
      <br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <button class = "click-to-close">CLOSE</button>
    </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr class = "expand-row">
    <td>Click to expand-1</td>
    <td>Click to expand-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class = "expand-data">
    <td colspan = "2">
      <br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <button class = "click-to-close">CLOSE</button>
    </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr class = "expand-row">
    <td>Click to expand-1</td>
    <td>Click to expand-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class = "expand-data">
    <td colspan = "2">
      <br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <button class = "click-to-close">CLOSE</button>
    </td>
  </tr>   
</table>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#table .expand-row').on('click', function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('not-expand-row')){
      var index = $(this).index('#table .expand-row');
      $('#table .expand-data').eq(index).css('display', 'table-row');
    }
  });

    $('#table .click-to-close').on('click', function(){
    var index = $(this).index('#table .click-to-close');
    $('#table .expand-data').eq(index).css('display', 'none');
    $('#table .expand-row').eq(index).addClass('not-expand-row');
  });
});
</script>
```