# What are some best practices for expandable table columns that could be used for choosing specific criteria?

Tags: html-table, datatable

So I am looking for examples where user can configure some columns (probably on the left side of the table), while information on the right changes accordingly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: someone already give answer here check it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3897511/6631280